# Creating a searchable list of two data types in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, struct, arraylist

Taking beginning Data Structures in C# class, trying to make a searchable arraylist of a string and an int referenced together (name and number).I need to be able to search for the name, and retrieve both the name and the number it's attached to. I was told I can use an arraylist of structs, but have never used structs. Any simple explanation how, or a better way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using an `ArrayList` at all suggests your course is rather out of date - `List<T>` has been preferred for almost all uses since .NET 2, which came out in 2005... and if you want to make a searchable data structure, is there any reason you've been instructed to use a list instead of the more obvious `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using something like a hash for this as an `ArrayList` of structs is a bit square peg round hole.

You declare a struct just like a calss.

```
public struct Foo {
    public String Bar { get; set; }
    public Int32  Biz { get; set; }
}
```

And you can make an array list of then as you would with any type

```
var list = new ArrayList();
list.add(object);
```

The other issue here is that `ArrayList` isn't generic, it will cast everything to `Object` which means you will have to cast everything back to type `Foo` to work with it.

```
var foo = (Foo)list.item(0);
```

You would be much better off, if you have to go the route of List instead of Hash using a generic list class like `List` and declaring its type;

```
var list = List<Foo>();
var foo = new Foo { Bar = "Hello World", Biz = 1 };
list.add(foo);
```

As for searching a list, I prefer to use the `LINQ` methods, because they are quick to code and easy to read.

```
var matches = list.Where( x => x.Biz > 1 );
```

But if you cannot do that then iteration always works

```
var matches = new List<Foo>();
foreach ( var foo in list ) {
    if ( list.Biz > 1 ) {
        matches.add(foo);
    }
}
```